# Complexity $O(\Delta \log n)$ for a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

I am not sure whether I am understanding this correctly, so I wanted to check: if we have $O(\Delta \log n)$ where $\Delta$ is the maximum degree of a graph and $n$ is the number of vertices in this graph, then if $\Delta$ is bounded, we can say that

$O(\Delta \log n)\subseteq O(\log n)$?

Comment: In what way is $\Delta$ bounded?

Comment: Not specified here, but I meant that if we assume for a certain subset of graphs $\Delta$ to be bounded.

Comment: Yes. With respect to the set of all graphs for which $\Delta\le C$, for some constant $C$, then $O(\Delta \log n)=O(\log n)$.

Comment: To clarify - is $\Delta$ always bounded from above by a constant? Can it grow as the number of nodes grow?